# Using a pull point subscription and PullMessages with an ONVIF camera

Tags: events, subscription, ip-camera, onvif

I developed a video surveillance program and I need to connect to an Axis camera using the ONVIF protocol to read the events.

When I use the `CreatePullPointSubscription` request, I get an address but I do not know how to use the parameter `ReferenceParameters dom0: SubscriptionId` in the `PullMessages` request.
It always returns an `InvalidArgs` fault.

How can I correctly apply the subscription ID to the `PullMessages` request?

Answer (score 1):

Put the `"dom0: SubscriptionId"` line into the Pullmessages request XML's .

e.g.:

```
<soap ...>
  <soap:Header>
    "dom0: SubscriptionId" You full SubscriptionId line comes here.
  </soap:header>
</soap>
```